# Use Python to calculate m-th order falling factorial

Tags: python, combinatorics, numerical-methods

Falling factorial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

How to use Python to compute it? My attempt

```
def factorial(gamma, m):
    prod = 1
    for i in range(m):
        prod *= (1-gamma-i)
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't you answering the question in your answer?

Comment: From a programmer's point of view a function named `[falling_]factorial(n, m)` should return the falling factorial of `n`, and be called with `1-gamma`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the return statement.

```
def factorial(gamma, m):
    prod = 1
    for i in range(m):
        prod *= (1-gamma-i)
    return prod
```

1 - γ = x

```
factorial(-4, 1) = 120
```